# Triggers in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, triggers

I have a question on this WPF-xaml code. Haven't used xaml alot but manage to get quite what I wanted with this code. But I feel that it isn't good practise at all. First, I would like to change the row from red to green or gray depending on some values in a certain cell. Do I really have to keep one trigger for each cell, or is there anyway to do the same trigger on the whole row? I would also like to set a specific color when a row is selected, but the style doesn't seem to support "IsSelected"...

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="200,50,5,5" ItemsSource="{Binding}" Name="dataGrid1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" EnableRowVirtualization="True" SelectionChanged="dataGrid1_SelectionChanged" MouseDoubleClick="dataGrid1_MouseDoubleClick">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" Header="File name" Binding="{Binding Path=Filename}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#68FF0000" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Errorcode}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Filename}" Value="File not created">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" Header="Weight" Binding="{Binding Path=Info1}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#68FF0000" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Errorcode}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Filename}" Value="File not created">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" Header="Rfid" Binding="{Binding Path=Info1}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#68FF0000" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Errorcode}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Filename}" Value="File not created">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" Header="Date/Time" Binding="{Binding Datetime, StringFormat=\{0:yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss\}}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#68FF0000" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Errorcode}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Filename}" Value="File not created">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="1*" Header="Error code" Binding="{Binding Path=Errorcode}">
                <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#68FF0000" />
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Errorcode}" Value="0">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Filename}" Value="File not created">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
            </DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very experienced with `DataGrid`, so this might not be the best option, but I think you can achieve what you're after by styling the Row, rather than the individual Columns:

```
    <DataGrid <!-- Your settings here -->>
        <!-- Your column definitions here -->
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Errorcode}"  Value="0">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGreen" />
                        <!-- Other Setters -->
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Filename}" Value="File not created">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightGray" />
                    </DataTrigger>

                    <!-- Other Triggers -->
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red" />
                        <!-- Other Setters -->
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
    </DataGrid>
```

Good luck.